# How android Compat class work

Tags: android

There are two classes

```
1) AppCompatActivity
2) GestureDetectorCompat.
```

As per the android docs these classes are provided support older android platform. I am wondering how this work. Although GestureDetector and GestureDetectorCompat have same API. How GestureDetectorCompat work in older platform in which GestureDetector is not present?

Comment: By replicating the functionality that is present in the newer version.

Answer (score 5):

> How GestureDetectorCompat work in older platform in which GestureDetector is not present?

There is no "older platform in which `GestureDetector` is not present". `GestureDetector` has been around since API Level 1.

However, the API for `GestureDetector` has changed over the years, with some methods being added in newer API levels. `GestureDetectorCompat` implements the newest API and gracefully degrades on older devices. You can see exactly what `GestureDetectorCompat` does by [reading its source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/android-6.0.1_r63/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/GestureDetectorCompat.java).

In general, classes whose names end in `Compat` do the same thing: implement the latest API, and either:

- Pass through methods to the platform implementation, if the device is running a new-enough version of Android
- Implement some backport of the functionality, or
- Simply ignore the request, as the feature cannot readily be replicated on the older device